# Why CountVectorizer.fit_transform is no fitting (8, BHADRA) from code below as it is supposed to fit every value present in vocabulary?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-processing

I need to fit every word(values) present in vocabulary as it is no fitting 8 and BHADRA for the code given below

```
feature_names=['1', '10', '2', '2079', '207901', '207902', '207903', '207904', '207905', '207906', '207907', '207908', '207909', '207910', '207911', 
               '207912', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '?', 'ASAR', 'ASOJ', 'BAISAKH', 'BHADRA', 'CHAITRA', 'FALGUN', 'JESTHA', 'KARTIK', 'MAGH', 
               'MANGSIR', 'POUSH', 'SHRAWAN', 'all', 'bank', 'bottom', 'by', 'class', 'deposit', 'in', 'is', 'last', 'lending', 'month', 'of', 'over', 
               'show', 'the', 'time', 'top', 'trend', 'view', 'what', 'year']
qsn_processed=['view', 'bottom', '8', 'lending', 'bank', 'in', '207905', 'BHADRA']
#setting the items of feature_names as 1 if it is present in qsn_processed
new_x = {}
for x in feature_names:
    if x in qsn_processed:
        new_x[x] = 1
    else:
        new_x[x] = 0

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# convert the dictionary to a list of strings
new_x_list = [' '.join([k]*v) for k,v in new_x.items()]
print("Items in new list is:")
print(new_x_list)

print("\nThe values that are not null along with their index are:\n")
for item in new_x_list:
  if item != '':
    print(item, " : ", new_x_list.index(item))
print("\n")
# create the vectorizer object and fit_transform the data
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=feature_names)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(new_x_list)
print("After fitting")
print(X)
print("\n")

# convert the dictionary to a string
new_x_str = ' '.join([k for k in new_x.keys() if new_x[k] == 1])

# transform the string using the vectorizer
X = vectorizer.fit_transform([new_x_str])

# print the shape of the resulting matrix
print(X)
```

I need to fit every word(values) present in vocabulary

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.